# How to move branch HEAD from one branch to anonther

Tags: git

A have such hierarchy in Git:

```
- master \
         - feature1 
         - feature2 \
                    - mybranch
```

feature2 have 20 additional commits from feature1.

I created new branch(mybranch) and accidentally found that it was created from wrong feature. All my changes in new files, and doesn't affect any files from feature1 or feature2.

How I can move my branch HEAD from feature2 to feature1?

Comment: That sounds like a `rebase`.

Comment: As melpomene mentioned, you can use `git rebase -i feature2` and pick commits in interactive mode.

Comment: Why `-i`? I'd just `git checkout mybranch; git rebase feature1`.

Comment: @melpomene no, either a 'rebase onto' (easier) or an interactive by selecting only the wished commits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `git rebase --onto` feature that is exactly to do that.

First, be sure to have 'mybranch' checked out. 
Then:

```
git rebase feature2 --onto feature1
```

You are telling git to take all the commits between 'feature2' and the tip of the current branch 'mybranch' and re-apply them onto 'feature2'.

Ps: That's not a 'normal' rebase that you should do (interactive or not) or you will end up with also all the 20 commits introduced by 'feature2'

Comment: A word of prosaic explanation would be very nice here.

Comment: I was but my baby started crying at the same time. Now I can ;-)

Comment: Been there myself. +1